# Multi site installation with multiple domains ie(www.exampleone.com, www.exampletwo.com)

Tags: multisite

I want to do a multi site installation of 13 websites with 13 different domain names. ie www.exampleone.com,www.exampletwo.com etc. I have seen examples of multi sites in Wordpress with **sub domains & sub folders**. Am not sure whether it is possible with **multiple domains**. What I have in my mind is to install multi sites with sub domains and do domain masking to achieve this. What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completly sure but as far as I know that should work with the plugin "[WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)"

Comment: The [WP Multi Network plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/faq/) will work too -